# Need custom pagination for wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, pagination

I am using the following code, To display all post for a particular category

```
    <?php
   $random_post = new WP_query(); 
  $random_post->query('cat='2'); 
  while ($random_post->have_posts()) : $random_post->the_post(); 
  the_title(); 
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

And it is working fine but i need a custom pagination , i just want to display only 5 post in a page.if you have any idea please let me know asap.